# Regex Pattern to identify Dash and 3+ alphanumerics

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying out many `regex` patterns to match following condition:

The string should end with a dash (-) and 3+ alphabets or underscores.

For example: `-xyz`, `-abc1_4`, `-uvw`. Anything is fine before dash.

Closest I could reach was to write individual scenarios: `.*\b(xyz)$` or `.*\b(uvw)$` which recognizes pattern ending with xyz , uvw .

The moment I add a dash, it is `.*\b(\-xyz)$`, `-xyz` is not recognized .

I am using following code in `Salesforce Apex Trigger`.

```
Pattern.matches('.*\b(xyz)$', stringToMatch);
```

I am looking for wider approach that can cover any occurrence of 3+ alphabets after the dash in the end of the string.

Comment: Is there any restriction on which characters are allowed before the `-`?

Comment: Which programming language, text editor, IDE, or other application or software tool are you using to apply these regular expressions?

Comment: Also, `1_4` is not alphabetic (at best it's alphanumeric in the loose regex sense where the underscore is included in the set of "word characters"), so do you want to match that or not? Please edit your question to remove this ambiguity. Thanks!

Comment: @TimPietzcker I have updated my question to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code  :

```
.*-[a-zA-Z]{3,}$
```

**Explanation:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the end of line respectively:

```
(?i)-[a-z]{3}\w*$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vA0bT8)

Answer (score 0):

With underscore and alpha/numbers

```
-[0-9a-zA-Z_]{3,}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the word boundary from your regex:

```
(-\w{3,})$
```

Comment: Thanks for the \W , making it comprehensive.

Comment: @user2989971: It's `\w` (lowercase), `\W` uppercase means the exact opposite!